# Pass multiple arguments from a text file to a bash script

Tags: bash

I have a bash script that takes three arguments, and I have a text file with three columns. I'd like the script to take the the text file's first, second, and third columns as the first, second, and third arguments of the bash script.

I'm a beginner with shell scripting, and am running fairly simple programs where efficiency is not very important, so simpler fixes would be appreciated :)

**Here's an example of what I'd like to do.**

*I have a text file called food.txt with the following text:*

```
fruits apples bananas
vegetables kale broccoli
meats pork beef
desserts cake pie
```

*And I have a menu.sh script like this*

```
#!/bin/bash

arg_1=$1
arg_2=$2
arg_3=$3

for arg_1 in $(cat food.txt)
do
    echo "${arg_1}:${arg_2},${arg_3}"
done
```

*I would like menu.sh to output this:*

```
fruits:apples,bananas
vegetables:kale,broccoli
meats:pork,beef
desserts:cake,pie
```

*But instead it outputs this:*

```
fruits:,
apples:,
bananas:,
vegetables:,
kale:,
...
```

Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The right way with **`bash`**'s **`read`** function:

```
#!/bin/bash

while read -r arg_1 arg_2 arg_3; do 
    echo "${arg_1}:${arg_2},${arg_3}"
done < food.txt
```

https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Bash-Builtins

Comment: TLDP is not a good resource _The TLDP bash guides are outdated, and in some cases just plain wrong. There's a reason they are not in the topic._ (greybot on #bash@freenode)

Comment: @GillesQuenot, GNU version should be enough, I suppose

Answer (score 0):

You met [*bash word spliting*](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/wordsplit).

Check [bash FAQ 1](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001)

You need to use

```
while read -r a1 a2 a3; do
    echo "$a1:$a2:$a3"
done < file
```

Answer (score 0):

```
cat food.txt | while read line
do
  header="$(echo "$line" | cut -f1 -d' ')"
  fields="$(echo "$line" | cut -f2,3 -d' ' | tr ' ' ,)"
  echo "$header:$fields"
done
```

If you ever add another field / column you can just change that `2,3` to be `2,3,4`  or `2-4`. If you ever have a variable number of fields per line, you can change it to `2-`.

Answer (score 0):

Another interesting (but not optimal) way to achieve this is using IFS var(Internal Field Separator). It's used within bash to tell how to separate fields, in this case, in a for loop:

```
#!/bin/bash

file=$(cat food.txt)
IFS_OLD=$IFS
IFS=$'\n'
for line in $file; do
        name=$(echo "$line" | cut -d' ' -f1 )
        element1=$(echo "$line" | cut -d' ' -f2)
        element2=$(echo "$line" | cut -d' ' -f3)
        echo "$name:$element1,$element2"
done
IFS=$IFS_OLD
```

Note that is important to backup and restore original IFS value. As I said, is not optimal, the other answers are better, but this still being another option

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you could do:

```
#!/bin/bash

IFS=$'\n'                                                                   
for arg in $(cat food.txt); do                                           
     echo  $arg | awk '{ print $1":"$2","$3 }'                               
done
```

or:

```
#!/bin/bash

awk '{ print $1":"$2","$3 }' food.txt
```